# useEffect causing infinite loop when contains a dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am creating an app that is similiar in function with instagram and i have come across an issue when posting a new photo. When a user posts a new photo it is saved into this state.

`const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);`

When the page renders and the useEffect runs the image is not displayed on the screen because it is async, so what i did was add "posts" as a dependencies to the useeffect. This created an infinite loop i think because it calls itself but i am unsure of any other way of going about this. This is the useEffect code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);
      setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
    }
    getPosts()
  }, [])
```

Comment: How are you using `posts` in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Adding `posts` in the dependency array tells React to call the useEffect whenever `posts` state is updated. Then again, you are updating the `posts` state inside the useEffect. That's what causes the infinite loop.

I think you should just render the page after the `posts` are loaded.

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      {posts && <>{/* Render content here */}</>}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: how can i wait until posts is fully loaded

Comment: I've updated the answer. See if that works. I need to see the full component code to give a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that the useEffect is causing an infinite loop when **posts** is in the dependency array.
Your useEffect dependency array does not need to contain your 'posts' useState because your React component will **re-render** itself when the state changes automatically assuming that your posts state is being used to display content.

Comment: it does not rerender because i loop through each post and create a react component using the post as the data

Comment: If the post components you're rendering are children of the component which holds the posts state, your component should still be re-rendering with the new post components. Could you post the code of your full component?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand,

You can wait for the API response before showing the image,
so you could add a new loading state which will turn into false once the API request is completed.

Check the code below

```
function App() {
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

 useEffect(() => {
const getPosts = async () => {
  try {
  const data = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);
  setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
   } catch {
    // handle errors
   } finally {
     setLoading(false)
   }
}
getPosts()
}, []);


return (
 {!loading && posts.map(post => <p>{post.image}</p>)}
)
```

}